# Can I access this _normalize method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

If we look at the source of `jquery.ui.autocomplete` they've got this:

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {
    // *snip*

    _normalize: function( items ) {
        // assume all items have the right format when the first item is complete
        if ( items.length && items[0].label && items[0].value ) {
            return items;
        }
        return $.map( items, function(item) {
            if ( typeof item === "string" ) {
                return {
                    label: item,
                    value: item
                };
            }
            return $.extend({
                label: item.label || item.value,
                value: item.value || item.label
            }, item );
        });
    },

        // *snip*
});

$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
    escapeRegex: function( value ) {
        return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    },
    filter: function(array, term) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
        return $.grep( array, function(value) {
            return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
        });
    }
});
```

Is it possible for me to call that `_normalize` method with my own items?

I'm not really sure how this all gets put together internally. I was trying things like `$.ui.autocomplete._normalize` but that seems to be undefined. So does `$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex` for that matter, which I find weird, because it looks like they're extending it right there...

Comment: autocomplete.prototype maybe?

Comment: @Joe: Correct. I just discovered this myself. Make it an answer and I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$.ui.autocomplete.prototype` to access those members